# Toggle border around checkbox label on click using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, flask

I have an app that prints out the contents of a list (using Python/Flask). Each item is a checkbox input, however I've hidden the checkboxes with CSS. Visually I'm trying to make it so when the user clicks the label text, the item is marked checked (hidden) and a border shows up around the text to confirm.

Once all selections have been made, the submit button sends everything back to Flask for processing. The functionality is all there and working. I am just having the hardest time with the visual aspect of toggling the border.

HTML (There are actually two columns like this but for simplicity I'll just put one):

```
<form action="/choices" method="post">

  <div class="left-col-results">
    {% for i in range(0, toplen) %}
    <label class="left-label-check">
      <input class="form-check-input-left" type="checkbox"
                                   name="checked" value="{{ top[i] }}">{{ top[i] } 
    </label>
    <br>
    {%endfor%}
</div>
```

The main problem seems to be the following jquery. I found this on another post and it does what I want visually, however the `e.preventDefault` kills the checkbox functionality:

```
$('.left-label-check').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).toggleClass('text-border');
    });
```

If I remove it:

```
$('.left-label-check').on('click', function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('text-border');
    });
```

It no longer adds the border! Any help is greatly appreciated.

****UPDATE:

Finally got it working. I didn't have the correct ajax link.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And used this syntax to toggle the class:

```
<label for="idl{{i}}" class="choice">{{ top[i] }}</label>



$(document).ready(function(){
        $('label.choice').click(function(){
       $(this).toggleClass("text-border");
     });
    });
```

Now it works as planned.

Comment: did you try to remove `e.preventDefault();` ?

Answer (score 1):

Because you hide input so you can put tags in different way.

If you put `<label>` after `<input>` and use `for=<input_id>` in `label` then you don't need JS and you can do it only with CSS:

```
input:checked + label {border: 1px solid red}
```

Code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string('''
<style>
   input:checked + label {border: 1px solid red}
</style>

<form action="/choices" method="post">
  <div class="left-col-results">
  {% for item in top %}
    <input id="id{{ loop.index }}" class="form-check-input-left" type="checkbox" name="checked" value="{{ item }}">
    <label for="id{{ loop.index }}" class="left-label-check">{{ item }}</label>
    <br>
  {%endfor%}
  </div>
</form>''', top=['a', 'b', 'c'])

app.run()
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it still doesn't seem to be working. I can click the text and the checkbox registers, but the border still won't change.

Comment: did you changed HTML - put `label` directly after `input`, not around `input`? Did you use `for=` in label with name from input ? Example code works for me.

Comment: Yes. I double checked everything is the same. Weird.

Comment: if you run it on server or keep full code on GitHub (or similar) then add url to see it.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe this is what you are looking for, although this is the VanillaJS way of doing it:

```
var leftLableCheck = document.querySelector('.left-label-check');
var checkbox = document.querySelector('[type=checkbox]');

leftLableCheck.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.setAttribute('class', 'text-border left-label-check')
});

checkbox.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Basically, we grab the parent label element, and the child checkbox element first:

```
var leftLableCheck = document.querySelector('.left-label-check');
var checkbox = document.querySelector('[type=checkbox]');
```

Then, we attach 'click' event listeners to each, but we stop the propagation of the click event on the checkbox itself so it doesn't bubble back up and run the code in our label listener twice:

```
leftLableCheck.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.setAttribute('class', 'text-border left-label-check')
});

checkbox.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here's a link to a CodePen where you can see it working. I don't hide the checkbox, that way you can see it get's checked and unchecked.

[Button Text Box CodePen](https://codepen.io/DanielSchroederDev/pen/PoYZxwQ)

Comment: This only seems to work for the first item on the list. Everything is inside of a For loop so I'm not sure what's going on.....